# Verify a Tensor Differential Identity

Tags: vectors, tensor-products, tensors

I would like to show that the ID below holds:

$$(n \cdot \nabla n)=1/2 \nabla(n \cdot n)-(n \times(\nabla \times n))$$

Using the Einstein notation I've come up with:

$$(n \times(\nabla \times n))_i=\epsilon_{ijk} n_j (\nabla \times n)_k \\
= \epsilon_{ijk} n_j \epsilon_{klm} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_l} n_m \\$$

Now, $\epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{klm}=\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}- \delta_{im}\delta_{jl}$
which is 1,-1,or 0 depending on the indices. And$\delta$ is the usual kronecker delta.

So,
$$(n \times(\nabla \times n))=(\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}- \delta_{im}\delta_{jl})n_j
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_l}n_m \\ = n_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}n_j - n_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}n_i $$

I'm stuck here now. How can I simplify it and where does the factor of 1/2 come from?

Comment: Post your work so some people can assist you!

Comment: With the current version, you're pretty much done. All that's left is 1) rewrite $n_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} n_j$ in terms of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}n_j n_j$, 2) convert back to $\nabla$-notation.

Comment: That is my dilemma. How do I do this?

Comment: SO the term to the right can be written $n_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} n_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} n_j n_i = \nabla n \cdot n $ correct?

Comment: I'm really just unsure where that 1/2 comes from...

Answer (score 1):

Use Einstein summation notation. It simplifies the process considerably.

Note that:
$$(\nabla \times n) = \epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} n_j e_k$$

Answer (score 0):

Think done like this:

```
curl.curl = div.grad - grad.div
```

Replace the first  **n**  with **curl A**

Answer (score 0):

Start with,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\nabla} (\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{n}) & =
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} (n_kn_lg^{kl})  \\
& =g^{kl}n_k\frac{\partial n_l}{\partial x^i} 
+g^{kl}n_l\frac{\partial n_k}{\partial x^i} \\
& =n^l\frac{\partial n_l}{\partial x^i} 
+n^k\frac{\partial n_k}{\partial x^i} \\
& =2 n^l\frac{\partial n_l}{\partial x^i} 
\end{align}
Next note that,
\begin{equation}
(\mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{n})^k =
\epsilon^{klm} \frac{\partial }{\partial x^l} n_m
\end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{n}\times(\mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{n})
=
\epsilon_{ijk}n^j
\epsilon^{klm} \frac{\partial }{\partial x^l} n_m
\end{equation}
From the properties of $\epsilon$,
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon^{klm} =
\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon^{lmk} =
\delta^{lm}_{ij}=\delta^l_i\delta^m_j-\delta^l_j\delta^m_i 
\end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{n}\times(\mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{n})
& =
\delta^l_i\delta^m_j n^j \frac{\partial }{\partial x^l} n_m
- \delta^l_j\delta^m_i n^j \frac{\partial }{\partial x^l} n_m \\
& = n^j \frac{\partial n_j }{\partial x^i} 
- n^j \frac{\partial n_i}{\partial x^j} 
\end{align}
So we can write,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{\nabla} (\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{n})
- \mathbf{n}\times(\mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{n})
\end{equation}
as,
\begin{equation}
n^l\frac{\partial n_l}{\partial x^i}
-\left(
n^j \frac{\partial n_j }{\partial x^i} 
- n^j \frac{\partial n_i}{\partial x^j}
\right)
=n^j \frac{\partial n_i}{\partial x^j}
=\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{\nabla}\mathbf{n}
\end{equation}